# Display Custom Field on any page content. Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, field

I created a custom field for User profiles. These are the settings- field_test  Integer Text field.

How can I display this custom field on any page through the CMS?

Answer (score 0):

If it's attached to the user entity, you can insert this into page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print render($user_profile['field_test']); ?>
```